# Python 3: Basic arithmetic operations

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program to perform simple arithmetic operations.
I want the program to prompt the user for two numbers, and then calculate five
results:

- the sum
- the difference
- the product
- the quotient according to both integer
- the floating point division.

Now, I remember that in **Python 2**, that there was raw_input for strings and input for numbers in general.
However, I am just learning **Python 3**, and input is by default a string, and for numbers I have to specify the type of number I wish to have: i.e. int(input()) or float(input()).

So, for example, let's assume that I want to have exactly this output (using inputs 4 and 2.5):

```
What is the first number? 4
What is the second number? 2.5
The sum is 6.5
The difference is 1.5
The product is 8.0
The integer quotient is 2
The floating-point quotient is 1.6
```

I would type this code in **Python 2**:

```
x=input ("What is the first number? ")
y=input ("What is the second number? ")

print "The sum is", x+y
print "The difference is", x-y
print "The product is", x*y
print "The integer quotient is", int(x)/int(y)
print "The floating-point quotient is", float(x)/float(y)
```

However, I can't get it done in **Python 3**. This is the (wrong) code I am using:

```
x = int(input("What is the first number? "))
y = int(input("What is the second number? "))

print("The sum is: ", x+y)
print("The difference is: ", x-y)
print("The product is: ", x*y)
print("The integer quotient is: ", x/y)
print("The floating-point quotient is: ", x/y)
```

Obviously, I get an error message because my second input (y) equals 4.5, which is a **float** and not an **int** as defined by my input. I didn't bother putting float(x)/float(y) for the floating-point quotient because that would also be contradictory (thus an error).

I could of course put float instead of int like this:

```
x = float(input("What is the first number? "))
y = float(input("What is the second number? "))
```

But in this case, I will get 10.0 for my product (not 10), and my integer quotient is a float (1.6 instead of 2)

I find it really frustrating that in Python 3 I can't ask for a general type number for input (without having to specify if it will be float or int). Therefore, I'm stuck on such simple program, and would greatly appreciate any solution/ explanation.

Comment: `input()` wasn't for "numbers in general", it was for anything that, when evaluated in the Python interpreter, returns an object. Inserting `1 if True else 2` into an `input()` prompt returns the integer `1`.

Comment: It was also a horribly unsafe idea and not what you usually want, which is why they changed it.

Comment: Basically, the change is you're supposed to know what input you're expecting, or you should inspect it and determine what to do with it yourself. You can still `eval()` the string you get from `input()` yourself, and take proper precautions to prevent it from doing anything funny. Better yet, use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) - this should be as close to what you need while still being safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to parse the input as an `int`, and if that doesn't work, treat it as a `float`:

```
def float_or_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return float(x)

x = float_or_int(input("What's x?"))
y = float_or_int(input("What's y?"))
```

To get flooring division in Python 3, you have to explicitly ask for it with the `//` operator:

```
print("The integer quotient is:", x//y)
```

Note that this "integer quotient" operation doesn't really make sense for floating-point input.

Comment: Thank you for the help!
Sure , there are ways to go around this. I just thought that such a simple program would not require more lines of code.